# How to use "fill_factor" in spilu (scipy)

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, scientific-computing

I am using spilu in scipy. However there is an option call "fill_factor" which is quite unclear to me.

If fill_factor=100, does it mean the matrix is full; and fill_factor=50 means the matrix is half-full?